# PhpStorm 2017.1 remote php-cli in docker: Configuration php.ini file does not exist

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm

## PhpStorm PHP CLI interpreters

[image: PHSTORM]

There are two error infos:

> 1. Can not find php.ini
> 2. Can not find xdebug.so

## PHP container

But in my PHP container

[image: php container]

> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini exist
>   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so exist

## PHP Dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm

COPY ./sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list

# Init EVN
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get install -y \
        vim \
        git \
        libgearman-dev \
        libmemcached-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libmagickwand-dev \
        libmagickcore-dev

# Install PHP extensions
COPY ./extensions/* /home/
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-ttf --with-gettext --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/ \
        && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt mbstring pdo_mysql zip gd bcmath soap xmlrpc \
        && pecl install /home/memcache-3.0.8.tgz && docker-php-ext-enable memcache \
        && pecl install /home/memcached-2.2.0.tgz && docker-php-ext-enable memcached \
        && pecl install /home/gearman-1.1.2.tgz && docker-php-ext-enable gearman \
        && pecl install /home/redis-2.2.8.tgz && docker-php-ext-enable redis \
        && pecl install /home/msgpack-0.5.7.tgz && docker-php-ext-enable msgpack \
        && pecl install /home/xhprof-0.9.4.tgz && docker-php-ext-enable xhprof \
        && pecl install /home/xdebug-2.4.1.tgz


# PHP config
ADD php.ini.dev /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
ADD php-fpm.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf
ADD docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

# Composer
ADD composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: Better ask PhpStorm support team directly -- use "Submit a Request" link on top of the PhpStorm Forums page -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367219-PhpStorm